# How to take some rows in the manual order and then rest in the regular way

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting countries from database and would like to put some of them to the beginning by hand. The list should looks this way:

```
Y <- those rows should be chosen by hand
X
R 
A <- and the rest is going to be in the regular order
B
C
D
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when col = 'Y' then 1
            when col = 'X' then 2
            when col = 'R' then 3
            else 4
       end),
      col;
```

Comment: This is what I ment :)